# Ошибка в Remote SSH

Tags: visual-studio, ssh, extension, connection

Всем привет! Выводит ошибку в консоль "Couldnt establish connection to ip adress"

лог консоли :

```js
[19:00:31.751] Log Level: 2
[19:00:31.762] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+80.87.202.7", attempt 1
[19:00:31.763] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[19:00:31.763] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[19:00:31.763] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[19:00:31.764] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[19:00:31.764] "remote.SSH.configFile": C:\Users\uukeyi\.ssh\config
[19:00:31.764] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[19:00:31.764] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[19:00:31.764] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[19:00:31.764] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[19:00:31.764] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[19:00:31.765] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[19:00:31.765] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[19:00:31.765] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[19:00:31.765] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[19:00:31.765] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[19:00:31.766] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[19:00:31.772] VS Code version: 1.75.1
[19:00:31.772] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.96.0
[19:00:31.772] win32 x64
[19:00:31.774] SSH Resolver called for host: 80.87.202.7
[19:00:31.774] Setting up SSH remote "80.87.202.7"
[19:00:31.778] Using commit id "441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf" and quality "stable" for server
[19:00:31.782] Install and start server if needed
[19:00:33.118] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[19:00:33.162] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[19:00:33.166] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\uukeyi\.ssh\config"
[19:00:33.166] Remote command length: 6211/8192 characters
[19:00:33.166] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49156 -F "C:\Users\uukeyi\.ssh\config" "80.87.202.7" powershell
[19:00:33.169] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[19:00:33.388] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[19:00:33.388] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[19:00:54.419] > ssh: connect to host 80.87.202.7 port 22: Connection timed out
[19:00:54.435] > Попытка записи в несуществующий канал.
[19:00:55.700] "install" terminal command done
[19:00:55.701] Install terminal quit with output: Попытка записи в несуществующий канал.
[19:00:55.701] Received install output: Попытка записи в несуществующий канал.
[19:00:55.701] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[19:00:55.703] Resolver error: Error: 
    at g.Create (c:\Users\uukeyi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:584147)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\uukeyi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:582761)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\uukeyi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:680758)
    at async c:\Users\uukeyi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:643114
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\uukeyi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:646432)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\uukeyi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:644164)
    at async c:\Users\uukeyi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.96.0\out\extension.js:1:721750
[19:00:55.711] ------
```

``
Просит три раза пароль и потом не подключает. Пытался поменять в конфигурации плагинов корневой путь к config ssh не получилось тоже.

Конфиг ssh :

Host 80.87.202.7

HostName 80.87.202.7

User root

Путь к папке к конфигу : C:\Users\uukeyi.ssh\config

Comment: Мне кажется, или у вас пытается достучаться на порт 49156. Тем не менее, попробуйте запустить `ssh -vvv 80.87.202.7`, чтобы debug-информация стала бы доступной.

Comment: а куда это писать? просто первый раз юзаю remote ssh

Comment: Нет под рукой VS Code, попробуйте с cmd пока запустить `ssh -vvv -T -F "C:\Users\uukeyi.ssh\.ssh\config" "ваш_юзернейм@80.87.202.7`

Comment: Попробовал не работает к сожалению...

Comment: Не работает? Да там тонну информации должно было вывести на экран, как минимум.